# Nextjs custom 404 page not showing when accessing invalid url in netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, http-status-code-404, netlify

I've created a 404.js file in /pages folder on my Nextjs project, the 404 page is working perfectly when entering an error or invalid URL in local but when its deployed in netlify they showing the default netlify error page.

[image]

**version details**

```
"next": "^10.0.4", 
"react": "17.0.2",
```

Tried netlify's redirect rule, but nothing happened

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/404.html"
  status = 404
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution when randomly changed the redirects rule based on this article https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file

Here is my fix, it's working when redeployed after.

Create a netlify.toml file in the project directory and paste below code.

```
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/404"
  status = 404
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two solution from this page =>
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/01/16/redirect-rules-for-all-how-to-configure-redirects-for-your-static-site/

1. I added a `_redirects` file inside the /public folder like /public/_redirects. I then pasted `/*  /index.html  200` into the _redirects file.

redeploy your app and it's done

Or second way:

2. Add `netlify.toml` file to the root directory of your project and paste in to:

   ```
   [[redirects]]
      from = "/*"
      to = "/"
      status = 200
   ```

redeploy your app and it's done

Comment: Hey @MarioG8 thanks for the answer, I got related fix before your answer, its working. I've added it as A2A.

Comment: you are welcome  best regards !